# Sending commands to the Linux Terminal from a Java program

Tags: java, terminal, raspberry-pi, plink

I am currently working on a project where I need to send gcode text files to a TinyG controller using a Raspberry Pi. I can successfully do so from the Terminal on the Pi, but I would like to make a graphical user interface for my coworkers who don't know how to use the Terminal. I am using a command line program called Plink to send the text files to the TinyG VIA a usb connection. Basically, I need to figure out how to send commands to the Terminal from my GUI program, which is written in Java. The commands I use in the Terminal now are:

```
cd Desktop
cat name_of_file.txt | plink -serial /dev/ttyUSB0 -sercfg 115200,8,n,1,R
```

I know similar questions have been asked, but I have tried many solutions with no luck so far. I have tried using the following segments of code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c \"cat /path/to/file | plink -serial /dev/ttyUSB0 -sercfg 115200,8,n,1,R\"");
```

and

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "/path/to/file");
pb.directory(new File(/path/to/directory));
Process p = pb.start();
```

I am very new to Java and Linux, and am very lost on this issue. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the error you are getting when you run the above code

Comment: There is no error, it just doesn't do anything. I'm staring to question whether it's the Java code, or something completely different.

Comment: When you use a `ProcessBuilder`, you should try to get what is received on stdout and stderr of the `Process`. That could give a hint of where the problem actually lies.

Comment: @R0T0: How do you know that it is not doing anything? What would happen if you ran it via terminal, and what would you expect to happen when you run it via the java program?